# Remove rows from output file .CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv, export-to-csv

Can someone look in this code. It merges together .csv files in one file. 
I would like that 1st row from each .csv not to be taken in consideration because it's relevant information and I have to delete this manually from the new merged file.
Also I would like some explanation along new code (I'm new to VBA, but would love to learn)
Is this possible please?

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
        ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
        ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
        lpExitCode As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
        ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
        ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
        lpExitCode As Long) As Long
#End If


Public Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = &H400
Public Const STILL_ACTIVE = &H103


Public Sub ShellAndWait(ByVal PathName As String, Optional WindowState)
    Dim hProg As Long
    Dim hProcess As Long, ExitCode As Long
    'fill in the missing parameter and execute the program
    If IsMissing(WindowState) Then WindowState = 1
    hProg = Shell(PathName, WindowState)
    'hProg is a "process ID under Win32. To get the process handle:
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, hProg)
    Do
        'populate Exitcode variable
        GetExitCodeProcess hProcess, ExitCode
        DoEvents
    Loop While ExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE
End Sub


Sub Merge_CSV_Files()
    Dim BatFileName As String
    Dim TXTFileName As String
    Dim XLSFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim DefPath As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oFolder
    Dim foldername

    'Create two temporary file names
    BatFileName = Environ("Temp") & _
            "\CollectCSVData" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy-h-mm-ss") & ".bat"
    TXTFileName = Environ("Temp") & _
            "\AllCSV" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy-h-mm-ss") & ".txt"

    'Folder where you want to save the Excel file
    DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        DefPath = DefPath & "\"
    End If

    'Set the extension and file format
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007 or higher
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        'If you want to save as xls(97-2003 format) in 2007 use
        'FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
    End If

    'Name of the Excel file with a date/time stamp
    XLSFileName = DefPath & "MasterCSV " & _
                  Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy h-mm-ss") & FileExtStr

    'Browse to the folder with CSV files
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set oFolder = oApp.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select folder with CSV files", 512)
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        foldername = oFolder.Self.Path
        If Right(foldername, 1) <> "\" Then
            foldername = foldername & "\"
        End If

        'Create the bat file
        Open BatFileName For Output As #1
        Print #1, "Copy " & Chr(34) & foldername & "*.csv" _
                & Chr(34) & " " & TXTFileName
        Close #1

        'Run the Bat file to collect all data from the CSV files into a TXT file
        ShellAndWait BatFileName, 0
        If Dir(TXTFileName) = "" Then
            MsgBox "There are no csv files in this folder"
            Kill BatFileName
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Open the TXT file in Excel
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=TXTFileName, Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow _
                :=2, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, _
                Space:=False, Other:=False

        'Save text file as a Excel file
        Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Wb.SaveAs Filename:=XLSFileName, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Wb.Close savechanges:=False
        MsgBox "Your Excel file is here: " & vbNewLine & XLSFileName

        'Delete the bat and text file you temporary used
        Kill BatFileName
        Kill TXTFileName

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

THANKS

Comment: So, this (too) big code has to merge all csv files from a specific folder in a 'Master` one, named as "Current time.csv", saved in Documents, and now, you need to do the same, but skipping the header of each file. Is that assumption a correct one? CSV files have the same number of columns, I suppose and they look to be comma delimited. Is that also correct?

Answer (score 0):

You do not say anything and I must leave the office... Please test the next code. It assumes that my above assumptions (in the comment) are true. The code is commented in a way to make you understand its meaning. It uses standard VBA/VBScript functions. No API calls and bat files... It excludes first csv line from merging process.

The code is commented in a way to make it easy to be understood. If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications!

```
Sub testMeergeCSVFiles()
    Dim fullFilename As String, objFSO As Object, objTF As Object, arrIn As Variant
    Dim masterFullName As String, i As Long, strIn As String, strExt As String
    Dim finStr As String, foldName As String, wb As Workbook, xlsFullName As String

    masterFullName = Environ("TEMP") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy-h-mm-ss") & ".csv"
    xlsFullName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & "MasterCSV " & _
                                Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy h-mm-ss") & ".xlsx"
    foldName = GetFolderPath(ThisWorkbook.path & "\") ' it uses GetFolderPath function, starting from
                                                      ' ThisWorkbook path
    fullFilename = Dir(foldName & "\" & "*.csv") 'iterate in folder for csv files
    Do While fullFilename <> ""
        'If left(fullFilename, 9) = "TestMerge" Then 'only for testing reason (for me)
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile(foldName & "\" & fullFilename, 1)
                strIn = objTF.ReadAll 'extract all the content of the file
            objTF.Close

            arrIn = Split(strIn, vbLf): sep = vbLf ' put the strinig in an array
            'start of modification__________________________________________
            If UBound(arrIn) < 1 Then arrIn = Split(strIn, vbCr): sep = vbCr
            If UBound(arrIn) < 1 Then arrIn = Split(strIn, vbCrLf): sep = vbCr
            Debug.Print "Sep: " & Len(sep), Asc(sep) ' adapted here...
            'end of modification____________________________________________

            For i = 1 To UBound(arrIn) ' build the string which excepts first row
                If arrIn(i) <> vbLf Then strExt = strExt & arrIn(i)
            Next i

            If finStr = "" Then 'Build the final string to be loaded in Master CSV
                finStr = strExt
            Else
                finStr = finStr & strExt
            End If
        'End If
        strExt = ""
        fullFilename = Dir  'reinitialize the loop
    Loop

    If finStr = "" Then Exit Sub 'happening in case of no csv files found in the folder
    Open masterFullName For Output As #1
        Print #1, finStr 'dropping the string in the master csv file
    Close #1
    'Opening the master file in Excel:
    Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=masterFullName, origin:=xlWindows, StartRow _
                :=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, _
                Space:=False, Other:=False
    'Save csv file As Excel xlsx format:
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    wb.SaveAs fileName:=xlsFullName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Kill masterFullName
    MsgBox "MasterCSV Excel file saved as " & xlsFullName
End Sub
Private Function GetFolderPath(Optional strPath As String) As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog, sItem As String

 Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 With fldr
    .buttonName = "Select Folder"
    .Title = "Select .CSV files to be processed Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If strPath <> "" Then .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
 End With
NextCode:
 GetFolderPath = sItem
 Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your interest on this. Yes, all .csv files have the same number of columns, just the number of rows are different. I tried this code, but after selecting the folder with .csv files, it does not do anything.

Comment: Ups... I forgot to comment two lines used only by me, in order to test it. Please, refresh the page and test it again. It processed only csv files name starting with "TestMerge". There were more csv files in my testing folder and I wanted to select somehow the ones having the same structure...

Comment: It works but first and last row has data in columns from A to ALO. In between first and last row all is okay. It looks how it should. Some of the data is inserted in first and last row instead of been in a separate row.

Comment: @Andrew Cm: When you say "ALO", this should mean column "ALO"? If yes, this means the columns are double sized? If yes, what content do that problematic rows have? The same content recorded twice, or a line which should be below the problematic one has been added? I am asking all that in order to understand how your csv files are built. It did not happen with my test files, which ends in a `VbLf` character (carriage return) and I eliminated it, in order to avoid gaps between two consecutive csv contents. Can you put here a link to download three such csv files? Only if answering is not enough.

Comment: Data that should be in a row one under another, is on row 1. Please see picture, I can't share files, I'm sorry  https://imgur.com/oYWJBLw

Comment: If i have only 2 csv files for merging, than all data shows up in row one. If i have more than 4 csv files for merging data shows up exactly like in this picture . If I have a lot of csv files for merging, than last row its like the first row. So , some data shows up correctly, and other data no

Comment: It is a matter of line separator, I think... I used `VbLf` and some of them may be differently separated. I will adapt a little the code. After that, I will tell you to also test the updated version... It would also be possible to follow a different approach. I mean to process the string itself, without loading in an array and eliminate the first line in this way, searching for any line end separator. But this only later. In some minutes I will leave my office...

Comment: Adapted the code. Basically the code now tries all usual line separators (`VbCr`, `VbLf` and `VbCrL`f). Please clear your Imediate Window and see what the code returns after running. It must show something like "Sep:  1" or "Sep:  2". Please see if this changes something in the code behavior and tell me what it returns in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G being in IDE)... I will leave my office in some minutes. The modified area is separated by `start of modification___` -  `end of modification__` commented code lines. Do not forget to refresh THIS page...

Comment: Sep: 1Sep: 1
Sep: 1
Sep: 1
Sep: 1
Sep: 1
Sep: 1

Comment: And the output looks the same? I mean, with first and last rows double sized? I made a little modification to make `Debug.Print` return the ASCII code for the separator. Please, tell me what it returns for `Asc(sep)`.

Comment: Would it be easier to add some code to initial code, that opens the output file executes a filter on a specific word, and deleting all rows that contain that word?   Maybe it is not possible ?

Comment: It cannot be  `the same output`... Did you refresh the page? Does the code have `Debug.Print "Sep: " & Len(sep), Asc(sep)` line? I edited now and commented where the modification has been done. It should display Sep: 1   10 or 13...

Comment: Your code uses a primitive way to concatenate files, no offence. If you do not need first lines to be missing, this code will work without problems. If I would have some such csv files (like yours), I could see what line separator they use. This is what I try to find out doing these tests...

Comment: It's no offence .  Tried again  now  I get   " Sep: 1         10 ", but output is the same.

Comment: OK. We made a little progress, but need to dig deeper... Singe you cannot send me your csv files, please save the files from the [here](https://easyupload.io/ev74ha) archive in a specific folder and run the above code and see what you obtain. I would like to understand if the files themselves have problems, or the way in which your Excel installation opens the consolidated csv. In this regards, I would also suggest you (even for your existing files) to proceed in this way: Please, comment the code line `Kill masterFullName` and add after it this one: `Debug.Print masterFullName`.

Comment: Not enough space in the previous comment... So, the consolidated csv file will not be deleted, any more and its full name will be displayed in Imediate Window. Please browse to the file location and open it, but using Notepad, Wordpad, Notepad ++ (a text editor). Does it have the first and the last row as in Excel file, or it looks correct there?